# How to Install Node.js on IIS Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, iisnode, windows-10-desktop

I've installed Node.Js a few times and I cannot seem to get it to show up in iis for windows 10.

When I look in IIS10 for managed modules iisnode is not there and when I try to add it, it mentions something about adding it to the GAC.

From the videos I've watched it seems to be very easy for every one, they download it, and it just magically appears.

I did a nodejs in the command prompt and it shows that it is installed.

What do I need to do to properly install it so it work with IIS?

See Snap Shot, you can see that iisnode is not in the modules in iis for windows 10

[Snap Shot of My Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YTwE.jpg)

Comment: Why do you expect installing NodeJS to install iisnode?

Comment: Instructions on this [github](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode) seem very clear - most videos aren't as informative as the original documentation

Comment: Instructions on Github are not for IIS10